# Compress and delete the logs in logrotate

Tags: linux, unix, logrotate

I want to compress the logs older than 30 days and delete older than 90 days through logrotate. Can you please help me here how I need to configurate in logrotate conf file.

Logs has been creating according to time. I need to take backup only subversion logs from this path.

```
[svnadmin@svnarapp01:/opt/svn/logs/svnarapp01]ls subversion_201*
subversion_2014_12_14_00_00_00.log
subversion_2014_12_29_00_00_00.log  
subversion_2015_01_13_00_00_00.log
subversion_2014_12_15_00_00_00.log  
subversion_2014_12_30_00_00_00.log  
subversion_2015_01_14_00_00_00.log
subversion_2014_12_16_00_00_00.log  
subversion_2014_12_31_00_00_00.log  
subversion_2015_01_15_00_00_00.log
```

Logs will compress older than 30 days and delete older than 90 days. This process will run daily.

Comment: `man logrotate` , configuration: `compress`, `rotate`,... I think you need 2 files but I'm not sure. one for the 30 day period and one for the 90 day period.

Comment: Have this moved to **Super User**?

Answer (score 4):

`maxage` will not be applied to `.gz` files as they are not `.log` files.
You could try to define `postrotate` script as follows:

```
postrotate
       find /path/to/log/ -name "*.log.*.gz" -mtime +7 -delete
endscript
```

Please adjust the path and mtime based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try define something like this in logrotate.conf

```
/opt/svn/logs/svnarapp01/subversion_*.log {
    monthly
    compress
    maxage 90
}
```

This will compress log files older than 30 days and remove logs older than 90 days. 
You can find more parameters in logrotate man page.